# Less bounties even if more upvote

Tags: support, bounty, specific-answer

I want to understand why my question got less bounties even if my answer is the most upvoted. 
[How to train a model in nodejs (tensorflow.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953399/how-to-train-a-model-in-nodejs-tensorflow-js/59001232#59001232)

Comment: Well, ask the one that issued the bounty. I guess he found the other answer more useful ...

Comment: Re *"less bounties"*: Don't you mean no bounty? Isn't it either or for bounties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> **How is a bounty awarded?**
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration
>   of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of
>   24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award
>   icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the
>   answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)
>
> **If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted).** If two or more eligible
>   answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
>   is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
>   awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question
>   owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the
>   bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty
>   owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty
>   amount at the time of bounty expiration.
>
> As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a
>   bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

Emphasis added to the second paragraph. As your answer was the most upvoted, but was not accepted as the solution or awarded the bounty, it was not given the 500 reputation, but 250 (half the bounty amount).

Note that Alex has given multiple bounties on that thread, as can be seen in their [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376947/alex?tab=reputation) page. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001529/3484879) you are referencing (with a 500 rep bounty award) was most likely given in a previous bounty on the question.

Comment: I think, I got it. It is because there are many bounties offered

Comment: Correct @edkeveked . Alex awarded a bounty of 500 to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001529/3484879), however, you received a 250 rep bounty, due to having the most upvoted answer that wasn't accepted/awarded on a different bounty. A question can have multiple bounties awarded.